# Sphinx search order by tags

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx

I have 2 tables

```
Table 1: Profiles table: p_id, p_title, p_presentation, p_date

Table 2: Tags table: tag_id, profile_id, tag_text
```

I want to check the tags to match the search:

Ex:
Tags: car; red car; big car

When I search for "car", I want just the exact match. I don`t care about the "red car" tag.

For the rest i need a normal search (SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2) for example.

So I want to display the profiles with exactly tags (let`s say 20 profile results) followed by the next results, ordered by p_date for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I do it...

```
sql_query = SELECT p_id, p_title, ..., \
            GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id) AS tag_ids, \
            CONCAT('_SEP_ ',GROUP_CONCAT(tag_text SEPERATOR ' _SEP_ '),' _SEP_') AS tag_text \
            FROM Profiles LEFT JOIN Tags ON (profile_id=p_id)
sql_attr_multi = uint tag_ids from field;
```

Then you can use phrase operateor to search exact tags, eg

```
"_SEP_ car _SEP_"
```

which will not match "big car"

The field start/end modifiers wont work, because can have multiple tags per document.

Comment: Im using other method for sort: $cl->SetSelect("*,IN(tag_id,1)+IN(tag_id,2)+IN(tag_id,3) as mytags"); It works good with one exception. When I have for example 700 results..so I need to repeat IN(tag_id,n) 700 times, I get no results..for 400 results it works. Do you have other idea to loop the ids for order?

Comment: Fixed: $cl->SetSelect("*, IN(tag_id, 1, 2, 3, n) as mytags");

Answer (score 0):

From the [Sphinx docs](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.6/extended-syntax.html):

For instance, the query "^hello world$" (with quotes and thus combining phrase operator and start/end modifiers) will only match documents that contain at least one field that has exactly these two keywords.

You can use start and end modifiers to get the exact result. Use this with quote.

```
"^car$"
```

Hope this will help !

Comment: Yes, but not only to match that 2 words. I want tag_text = "hello world". field == search